# WSO2 API Manager - Setting 'CacheId' when clustering with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, configuration, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm clustering WSO2 API Manager (v1.10.0) across three servers (Gateway + Publisher/Store + Key Store) by following this guide:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+1.10.0

I am on Step 11a of the 'Installing and configuring the databases' section. This states the following:

> 11. To give the Publisher and Store components access to the registry database, open the /repository/conf/registry.xml file in each of these two components and configure them as follows:
>
> a. In the Publisher component's registry.xml file, add or modify the `dataSource` attribute of the `<dbConfig name="govregistry">` element as follows:

```
<dbConfig name="govregistry">
  <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>
<remoteInstance url="https://publisher.apim-wso2.com"> 
   <id>gov</id>
   <cacheId>user@jdbc:mysql://regdb.mysql-wso2.com:3306/regdb</cacheId>
   <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>
   <readOnly>false</readOnly>
   <enableCache>true</enableCache>
   <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>
<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
   <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
   <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>
<mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
   <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
   <targetPath>/_system/config</targetPath>
</mount>
```

However, I'm using Microsoft SQL Server, rather than MySQL, so the `cacheId` value doesn't look right to me.

How should the `cacheId` be configured for SQL Server please?

I have taken a look through the commented-out descriptions in the registry.xml file, but cannot figure this out.

Here is my WSO2REG_DB configuration:

```
<datasource>
    <name>WSO2REG_DB</name>
    <description>The datasource used by the registry</description>
    <jndiConfig>
        <name>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
        <configuration>
            <url>jdbc:sqlserver://***SERVER***:1433;databaseName=***DATABASE_NAME***</url>
            <username>WS02RegUser</username>
            <password>***REMOVED***</password>
            <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
        <driverClassName>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driverClassName>
            <maxActive>50</maxActive>
            <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
            <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
            <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
            <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
        </configuration>
    </definition>
</datasource>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cacheId - This is the cache id of the remote instance. Here the cache
>   id should be in the format of $database_username@$database_url, where
>   $database_username is the username of the remote instance database and
>   $database_url is the remote instance database URL.

Reference: https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/Remote+Instance+and+Mount+Configuration+Details#RemoteInstanceandMountConfigurationDetails-JDBC-basedRemoteInstanceConfiguration

Comment: Great. Thank you. That is exactly what I was after. 

Therefore, I think that my `cacheId` value should be `WS02RegUser@jdbc:sqlserver://***SERVER***:1433;databaseName=***DATABASE_NAME***`.

It's strange that this information isn't in the API Manager documentation.

Comment: Wait... I see now - The registry part (of API Manager) is its own WSO2 product and has it's own documentation.