# WSO2 Registry XML Configuration for remote instance

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

For one JDBC-based configuration , is the URL useful? According [Remote Instance and Mount Configuration Details](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance411/Remote+Instance+and+Mount+Configuration+Details),  The URL of the remote instance can be deduced as follows:

Let the URL of the destination server be https://localhost:9443/services. Then the URL of the remote instance will be https://localhost:9443/registry. Let the URL of the destination server be https://10.20.30.40:9445/webcontext/services. Then the URL of the remote instance will be https://10.20.30.40:9445/webcontext/registry.

But in the [APIM 2.0 deployment](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0#ClusteringAPIManager2.0.0-ConfiguringtheGateway), the publisher's configuration is as below:

```
<remoteInstance url="https://publisher.apim-wso2.com"> 
   <id>gov</id>
   <cacheId>user@jdbc:mysql://regdb.mysql-wso2.com:3306/regdb</cacheId>
   <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>
   <readOnly>false</readOnly>
   <enableCache>true</enableCache>
   <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>
```

Modify the /etc/hosts entries to map the relevant IP addresses to the remoteInstance URLs.

- 127.0.0.1 publisher.apim-wso2.com

Why does it use "https://publisher.apim-wso2.com" , but not "https://localhost:9445" ?

BTW, Is cacheId useful in JDBC-based configuration? if yes, what's the cacheId name rule? JDBC URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remoteInstance url` is not used in JDBC case.

`cacheId` is required. See this.

[WSO2 API Manager - Setting 'CacheId' when clustering with SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122947/wso2-api-manager-setting-cacheid-when-clustering-with-sql-server/39126857#39126857)